# Trying to get property of non-object CRUD

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a CRUD system for blog publications, but it's kinda strange, another developer (with more experience) looked to my coded and for him it's all right too, but this error (**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\genial\painel\inc\database.php on line 32**) remains appearing.

My database code:

```
<?php
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
function open_database() {
try {
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    return $conn;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    return null;
 }
}
function close_database($conn) {
try {
    mysqli_close($conn);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

function find( $table = null, $id = null ) {

    $database = open_database();
    $found = null;
    try {
        if ($id) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM" . $table . " WHERE id = " . $id;
            $result = $database->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $found = $result->fetch_assoc();
                }

            } 
           else {

              $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
              $result = $database->query($sql);

             if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $found = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
             }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = $e->GetMessage();
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
   }

close_database($database);
return $found;
}



 function find_all( $table ) {
    return find($table);
 }

 function save($table = null, $data = null) {
     $database = open_database();
     $columns = null;
     $values = null;
     //print_r($data);
     foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $columns .= trim($key, "'") . ",";
        $values .= "'$value',";
     }

     $columns = rtrim($columns, ',');
     $values = rtrim($values, ',');

     $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . "($columns)" . " VALUES " ($values);";
     try {
        $database->query($sql);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registro cadastrado com sucesso.';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Nao foi possivel realizar a operacao.';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
        }
      close_database($database);
    }

    function update($table = null, $id = 0, $data = null) {
        $database = open_database();
        $items = null;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $items .= trim($key, "'") . "='$value',";
        }

        $items = rtrim($items, ',');
        $sql  = "UPDATE " . $table;
        $sql .= " SET $items";
        $sql .= " WHERE id=" . $id . ";";
        try {
            $database->query($sql);
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registro atualizado com sucesso.';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Nao foi possivel realizar a operacao.';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
        }
        close_database($database);
    }
```

Sorry if it's not right idled.

I put an space on the code after the "FROM" at

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM" . $table . " WHERE id = " . $id;
```

The error remains the same but know on line 36 that is:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $found = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Turned the code on line 36 to:

```
$if (result = $database->query($sql)) {
```

The error disappeared, others problems not relative to **this** question happened.

Comment: Forgot to say: This error only appears when i'm trying to use the edit section, the "replace" from CRUD. The other's are working just fine.

Comment: Code you provided has a parse error

Comment: Always add new question info into the question itself via an edit.  This prevents readers having to comb through all of the comments to get the full story.  Please edit your question and delete your comment.

Comment: Please echo and post the actual query when you are receiving this error to show that all of the variables are coming through.  Also, please manually run your query in your database to see if it works there.

Comment: If your issue can no longer be replicated please delete your question.   If you don't do this, it will be closed by moderators (wasting their time) p.s. I hope you didn't actually put a `$` in front of your condition statement.  I assume this is a posting typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this question isn't closed as `off-topic -> typo generated`, I'd better provide an acceptable answer.

1. Add a space between `FROM` and `$table` in your `SELECT` query.
2. Check for a non-false result from your query.

Your new code could look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table`";
if ($id) {
    // assuming id has been properly sanitized
    $sql .= " WHERE id=$id";  // concatenate with WHERE clause when appropriate
}
if ($result = $database->query($sql)) {  // only continue if result isn't false
    if ($result->num_rows) {  // only continue if one or more row
        $found = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);  // fetch all regardless of 1 or more
    }
}
```

3. `$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . "($columns)" . " VALUES " ($values);";` has too many double quotes in it -- you can tell by how Stack Overflow highlights the characters.  I could say that you could clean up the syntax, but it would ultimately be best to scrap your script and implement prepared statements.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\genial\painel\inc\database.php on line 47. 
Line 47 is: if($result=$database->query($sql);  // only continue if result isn't false